# Nodes are not applying to the object

Tags: rendering, texturing, node-editor, color, color-management

Im using Blender 3.0 and very new with Blender
Ive followed a tutorial and built something cool, unfortunately i dont know the proccess of building it. Im not sure its an object at the moment.
Im trying to apply nodes to it so i could add texture and colors to the ring.
Hope you could tell me why its not working to me.
To simplify it, how do i connect between the nodes of texture and color  to the rings?
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8Ouf.jpg]

https://pasteall.org/blend/076e780aff6e4fcfa48fcdca5a7174c1

Comment: Are you trying to assign your material to the peaks? Maybe share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I added the file
Im trying to connect between the nodes in the shader editor to the object currently picked, the rings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spikes do not show the material because you added it to the object in the *Material Properties*, but the spikes are created with *Geometry Nodes* (you should mention that in the question). The material given to the object only affects the original mesh, not the spikes.

To set a material for the spikes, you have to open the *Geometry Node Editor* and put a *Set Material* node between the created instances and the *Group Output* node. Choose the material there to assign it to the spikes:

[image: gn material]

What I also noticed is that you have a *Join Geometry* node in there, too. It seems that you wanted to join the spikes with the original torus object - but that doesn't work because you've created a second *Geometry* socket on the *Group Input* node. This gives an error shown in the *Modifier Properties*: "Node group can only have one geometry input"

The original mesh of the torus comes from the first *Geometry* socket, the second holds no mesh information - therefore you don't need to join it with the other geometry anyway. If you want to combine the spikes with the torus and make them both show, disconnect the second *Geometry* socket from the *Join Geometry* and instead plug the first one in there.

Even better it would be, to get rid of the the second slot and the error message, to open up the sidebar by hitting <kbd>N</kbd>, then in the *Group* tab select the second "Geometry_ entry in the *Inputs* list and press the minus button to the right to delete it. Now there is only one *Geometry* input to choose from.

[image: delete unused input]

[image: joined geometry]

Comment: Thank you very much!
Much appreciation :)

Comment: @Shamash If this helped, you might consider accepting this answer.